# Bitrix - How to find last updated component or file in Bitrix

Tags: bitrix

I have updated one component file from the `Edit Mode` of Bitrix environment. I have written one statement and write exit to debug the code. But now I can't find the component which I have edited.

Is there any way to find last updated files or templates or component or any other way by which I can revert back that component?

I have updated component file from this page - CRM > Deals > Add New Deal page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edited CRM > Deals > Add New Deal page using "Edit page" button then check out `/crm/deal/index.php` file.

To check out what core files/system components were affected (if they were modified) you could use "Project Quality Control" tool:

1. Open Control Panel > Settings > Tools > Project Quality Control
2. Click "Release Project".
3. In checklist find "Project release" group and click "The system kernel was not modified".
4. Click "Run autotest".
5. Click "Detail report" link to see which core files was modified.

[image]

But the best way to figure out what files was modified is compare document root folder with the backup copy.

If you want to continue to edit the files then I recommend you to set up version control system (e.g. GIT).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its really help me.